# "populus chain new horton" command doesn't work

Tags: populus

I encounter my first serious issue with the populus tutorial when I try to execute the following command:

```
populus chain new horton
```

The output is:

```
Mac:tutorial admin$ populus chain new horton
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/populus", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('populus==2.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'populus')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/populus/cli/chain_cmd.py", line 38, in chain_new
new_local_chain(project.project_dir, chain_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/populus/api/utils.py", line 79, in new_local_chain
account = create_new_account(data_dir, password, **geth_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geth/accounts.py", line 116, in create_new_account
stderrdata,
ValueError: Error trying to create a new account
Command    : nice -n 20 geth --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi admin,debug,eth,miner,net,personal,shh,txpool,web3,ws --ws --wsaddr 127.0.0.1 --wsport 8546 --wsapi admin,debug,eth,miner,net,personal,shh,txpool,web3,ws --datadir /Users/admin/Documents/league_fiesta/ethereum/tutorial/chains/horton/chain_data --maxpeers 0 --networkid 1234 --port 30303 --ipcpath /Users/admin/Documents/league_fiesta/ethereum/tutorial/chains/horton/chain_data/geth.ipc --verbosity 5 --unlock 0 --password /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geth/default_blockchain_password --nodiscover --mine --minerthreads 1 account new
Return Code: 127
stdout: N/A
stderr:
`b'nice: geth: No such file or directory\n'`
```

I can't figure out how to solve this issue.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like maybe you don't have geth installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

populous expects `geth` to be installed and in your $PATH. Installing `geth` through something like homebrew should solve your issue.

Comment: You're right! I thought geth was already installed.

Comment: Glad it's fixed - hit that answer button too :)